# Custom mime-type failing to register

Tags: android, android-manifest, mime-types

I am trying to establish a custom mime-type for an application file format, "application/ikd". The goal is to launch the app when a user selects an appropriate file from the file manager. Later on I plan to expand this to launching from a URL and from email.

The app builds and installs cleanly to my Android device, yet when I go to the Samsung file manager, and locate a file, e.g."a.ikd", the device prompts me to search the store for an app instead of launching the app on the device. Clearly I must be missing something simple in the manifest, but I haven't been able to spot it in the simple app I am using to test.

Including the manifest below...any insight appreciated.

`

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
    android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication"
    tools:targetApi="31">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.MyApplication">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="*"/>
            <data android:host="*"/>

            <data android:mimeType="application/ikd"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ikd"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ikd"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ikd"/>
            <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ikd"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is likely not on the receiving side but on the sending side.

Here's for example how the standard [FileProvider](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/content/FileProvider#getType(android.net.Uri)) tries to infer the MIME type:

> If the associated file has an extension, the MIME type associated with
> that extension; otherwise application/octet-stream.

Internally, it looks the extension up in a predefined [Map](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap#getMimeTypeFromExtension(java.lang.String)). And since it's not aware of your custom type, it considers it binary (octet-stream).

I don't know the details of the Samsung file manager, but it probably has a similar logic.

In order to be able to receive a custom MIME type you probably need to define a custom `ContentProvider`.

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-creating